# Tikz edge labels: positioning relative to direction of edge

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am in the process of converting some old figures into Tikz, and have come across something which I'm sure Tikz must be able to manage, but haven't figured out how yet...

**Target picture:** Is here:

[image: This is what I'm trying to draw]

Note that there are 12 labelled edges, with each edge also having an arrow. For every edge, as I travel along the direction of the edge I see the arrow on the right (sloped in the same direction as the edge), and the label on the left (not sloped).

Here is an MWE attempt, using `sloped`, together with `above` and `below`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=2mm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y [count=\i] in {0/0,3/0,1/1,2/1,1/2,2/2,0/3,3/3}
  \node[vertex] at (\x,\y) (\i) {};
\foreach \s/\t [count=\i] in {1/7,7/8,8/2,2/1,4/6,6/5,5/3,3/4,5/7,2/4,8/6,3/1}
  \path (\s) edge node[midway,above] {\footnotesize \i} node[sloped,midway,below] {$\longrightarrow$} (\t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

Not quite right! As well as the numbering on the edges being, literally, above the centrepoint of the edge, the arrows are also not all pointing in the right direction.

I can, of course, break up the for loops and produce a satisfactory picture, but surely Tikz has a better solution?

Comment: For the arrows, you could add `allow upside down` to the node options.

Comment: `allow upside down` works nicely -- thank you! If I do this to the node labels too, then they're in the right places, but need to be returned to normal orientation... Does that help I wonder?

Comment: Maybe use `auto=left` for the nodes with the numbers and `auto=right` for the nodes with the arrows (the latter in combination with `allow upside down`). I can't test now unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option using conditionals to swap the positions fo the arrows and the text depending of the the `\orientation` value 0 or 1 in the foreach imputs; the arrows are drawing using the midway node sloped points like `node_name.east`, `nodename.west`; to control the direction other value is added in the foreach inputs `\dir`, using -> and <- notations. Sorry if it is not the most elegant but controls almost everything to get the desired result.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=1.5mm}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >={Stealth[length=3pt]}
    ]
    \foreach \x/\y [count=\i] in {0/0,3/0,1/1,2/1,1/2,2/2,0/3,3/3}{
        \node[vertex] at (\x,\y) (\i) {};
    }
    \foreach \s/\t/\dir/\orientation [count=\i] in {
        1/7/->/1,%1
        7/8/->/1,%2
        2/8/<-/0,%3
        1/2/<-/1,%4
        4/6/<-/0,%5
        6/5/<-/1,%6
        5/3/->/0,%7
        3/4/->/0,%8
        5/7/<-/0,%9
        2/4/<-/1,%10
        8/6/<-/0,%11
        3/1/<-/1%12
    }{
        \ifnum\orientation=0
            \draw (\s)
                -- (\t)
                node[
                minimum width=0.6cm,
                midway,
                above,
                sloped,
                label={[inner sep=2pt]-90:\scriptsize\i}
                ](temp){};
        \fi
        \ifnum\orientation=1
            \draw (\s) 
                -- (\t)
                node[
                minimum width=0.6cm,
                midway,
                below,
                sloped,
                label={[inner sep=2pt]90:\scriptsize\i}
                ](temp){};
        \fi
        \draw[\dir] (temp.west) -- (temp.east);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Arrows 5 is in the opposite direction...

Comment: Oh what a mistake, although I review for a while, thank you.

Comment: Although I'm reluctant to pass more arguments, this is a good general solution. For my specific case, adding `label={[inner sep=2pt]90:\scriptsize\i}` as you have, together with `allow upside down` to the second node (and removing the first node) is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is just for fun. The arrows adjust themselves a bit to the path they get attached at.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum
width=2mm},arrow right/.style args={#1/#2}{postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {%
\draw[-stealth]
(-1.5mm-\pgfdecoratedpathlength/8,{-1*#2*(1mm+min(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/16,1mm)}) -- 
(1.5mm+\pgfdecoratedpathlength/8,{-1*#2*(1mm+min(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/16,1mm)});
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (0,#2*2mm){#1};}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y [count=\i] in {0/0,3/0,1/1,2/1,1/2,2/2,0/3,3/3}
  \node[vertex] at (\x,\y) (\i) {};
\foreach \s/\t/\u [count=\i] in
{1/7/1,7/8/1,8/2/1,2/1/1,6/4/1,6/5/-1,5/3/-1,3/4/-1,5/7/1,2/4/1,8/6/1,3/1/1}
  \path (\s) edge[arrow right=\i/\u] 
  (\t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might be to add `auto=right` to the nodes with the numbers, and `allow upside down` to the nodes with the arrows.

[image]

Not that this is not exactly the same as your example picture, because not all numbers are right of the arrow.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=2mm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y [count=\i] in {0/0,3/0,1/1,2/1,1/2,2/2,0/3,3/3}
  \node[vertex] at (\x,\y) (\i) {};
\foreach \s/\t [count=\i] in {1/7,7/8,8/2,2/1,4/6,6/5,5/3,3/4,5/7,2/4,8/6,3/1}
  \path (\s) edge node[midway,auto=right] {\footnotesize \i} node[sloped,midway,above,allow upside down] {$\longrightarrow$} (\t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```